# Ruby Hash with integer keys changed to string keys

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I create a hash in ruby with integer keys and send it as a JSON response. This JSON is then parsed and the hash is converted back to ruby. The keys are now string literals.

I get it that JSON doesnt support integer keys but I came upon this method which basically parses the hash so that it has symbol keys.

```
JSON.parse(hash, {:symbolize_names => true})
```

Is there a similar function for obtaining back the original integer keys

```
a = {1 => 2}
a.keys
=> [1]
b = JSON.parse(JSON.generate(a))
b.keys
=> ["1"]
```

My hash is very complicated. The value itself is a hash which is supposed to have integer keys. There are multiple such levels of nesting

Comment: Sure, iterate over the keys, convert them to integers, and set their values to the original string keys' values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Nothing in JSON](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse-21) as far as I know, but conversion is easy:

```
json_hash = {"1" => "2" }
integer_hash = Hash[json_hash.map{|k,v|[ k.to_i, v.to_i ]}]
=> {1 => 2}
```

So, we take all key & value from the initial hash (`json_hash`), call to_i on them and get them in a new hash (`integer_hash`).

Even nesting is not blocking. You could do this in a method:

```
def to_integer_keys(hash)
  keys_values = hash.map do |k,v|
    if(v.kind_of? Hash)
      new_value = to_integer_keys(v) #it's a hash, let's call it again
    else
      new_value = v.to_i #it's a integer, let's convert
    end

    [k.to_i, new_value]
  end

  Hash[keys_values]
end
```

Comment: The problem is my hash is very complicated. The value itself is a hash which is supposed to have integer keys. There are multiple such levels of nesting

Comment: Then just do it recursively. Avdi Grimm [posted a method](http://devblog.avdi.org/2009/07/14/recursively-symbolize-keys/) that does that for YAML and strings/symbols, it should be trivial to combine that with Martin's answer to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

normal key transformation using built in method by passing required block

```
hash1 = {'1' => {'2' => 'val2', '3' => 'val3'}} 
p hash1.transform_keys(&:to_i)

{1=>{"2"=>"val2", "3"=>"val3"}}
```

nested key transformation solution by passing required block

```
class Hash
  def deep_transform_keys(&block)
    result = {}
    each do |key, value|
      result[yield(key)] = value.is_a?(Hash) ? value.deep_transform_keys(&block) : value
    end
    result
  end
end
hash1 = {'1' => {'2' => 'val2', '3' => 'val3'}} 
p hash1.deep_transform_keys(&:to_i)

{1=>{2=>"val2", 3=>"val3"}}
```